# Connect 3 raspberry pi to a VNC

Tags: raspberry-pi3

In my project I need to use 3 raspberry pi independently ,each one controll a relay that cut off/on thr power on a motor ,I want to control the 3 pi with a single desktop computer. My question is can I have 3 VNC on the same computer ,or there is a way to control the 3 raspberry pi from one VNC.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because not programming question.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you can control three RPI with one computer, but you need three Ethernet cable connected to the same computer.